# Upload Failed in Office Client after adding ADFS

Tags: authentication, office-integration, adfs, windows-authentication

We are attempting to add ADFS authentication to SharePoint in a combined Kerberos/ADFS setup. Clients connected to the internal network use Windows Authentication, and remote clients use ADFS for authentication. (We're using https://spautomaticsignin.codeplex.com/).
This works well except for local Office clients.

When a user tries to save a file to the SharePoint document library with an Office application, it says `Upload Failed: You are required to sign in to upload your changes to this location.` Clicking the Sign In button does not seem to do anything.

Looking at a network trace as Word attempts to sign in shows an HTTP request to `/_vti_bin/cellstorage.svc/CellStorageService` with a `FedAuth` cookie but no Authentication header, which gets a 401 response with the `WWW-Authenticate` header set to `Negotiate,NTLM`. Based on my understanding, Word should then re-try the request with the Kerberos ticket, but Word does not seem to retry at all.

We are using Office 2013 and 2016 and SharePoint 2013. ADFS is version 3.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Edit: It actually does not seem like Office clients are able to upload when remote. Other than Outlook, they do not seem to pick up the alternate URLs for the site.

Edit 2: OneNote seems to give a bit more information

> Error code: 0x803D001F) There was an error communicating with the endpoint at 'http://{SharePoint URL inside network}/_vti_bin/webs.asmx'.; The server returned HTTP status code '401 (0x191)' with text 'Unauthorized'.; The server requires HTTP authentication scheme 'negotiate'.